# web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction() always return "Returned error: nonce too low"

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

I used web3@1.00 in node.js to interact with private blockchain. And I write the code according to the official documents of web3@1.00.

```
    var Web3 = require('web3');
    var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
    
    
    var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8101');
    
    
    //get the privatekey
    var decryptPK = web3.eth.accounts.decrypt({"address":"68c5cb5aa9f568ae2a6ec530e982f4f1144f2d10",
    "crypto":{"cipher":"aes-128-ctr",
    "ciphertext":"96b6a86bd5ff16a5669975974eabba844bc414bc52d9cc36843b4f41e89d46b9",
    "cipherparams":{"iv":"6858473ac21c43e94add7e0b70306da5"},
    "kdf":"scrypt","kdfparams":{"dklen":32,"n":262144,"p":1,"r":8,
    "salt":"4dee1ee7cf929cd38938aaf0a6c83ceeb743348980052b6fb94ab139ae7e09db"}
    ,"mac":"f7d9bbd81f9c91ffa21e564e613bae57bd77c1914a6690f6018623ff2ce80845"},
    "id":"0eb12580-d11a-49f5-91bb-3592a530e4d8","version":3}
    , '123');
    var privateKey = new Buffer(decryptPK.privateKey.substring(2),'hex');
    
    
  //check the nonce
web3.eth.getTransactionCount('0x68c5cb5aa9f568ae2a6ec530e982f4f1144f2d10').then(console.log);
    
    var rawTx = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
        from: '0x68c5cb5aa9f568ae2a6ec530e982f4f1144f2d10',
        to: '0x7fdec66a5c1b69824dfe3bc29138fac9ddf13ed4',
        value: '1000000000',
        gas: 2000000
    }, decryptPK.privateKey)
    .then(console.log).rawTransaction;
    
    
    var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
    tx.sign(privateKey);
    
    var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
    
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'));
```

However, I always fail to send a transaction. The web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction() always return the error "nonce too low".

```
(node:78916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Returned error: nonce too low
(node:78916) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Please help me know how to fix this problem.

Comment: What does the `console.log` for `getTransactionCount` give? Do you get a different result if you explicitly include `nonce` in your tx object?

Comment: I just used getTransactionCount() to check the value of nonce, and the value is '1'. And I tried to set a current nonce, even set a relatively large value for the nonce, but still suggested ‘nonce too low’.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bit of code looks wrong:

```
var rawTx = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
    from: '0x68c5cb5aa9f568ae2a6ec530e982f4f1144f2d10',
    to: '0x7fdec66a5c1b69824dfe3bc29138fac9ddf13ed4',
    value: '1000000000',
    gas: 2000000
}, decryptPK.privateKey)
.then(console.log).rawTransaction;
```

I assume `rawTx` is `undefined` after this? You're trying to access a field called "rawTransaction" on a `Promise` object.

The code should probably look something like this (completely untested):

```
web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
    nonce: 1,  // Use the right nonce here, just hardcoding at 1 for the example.
    from: '0x68c5cb5aa9f568ae2a6ec530e982f4f1144f2d10',
    to: '0x7fdec66a5c1b69824dfe3bc29138fac9ddf13ed4',
    value: '1000000000',
    gas: 2000000
}, decryptPK.privateKey)
.then(tx => {
    var rawTx = tx.rawTransaction;
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(rawTx).on('receipt', console.log);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helps me fix the problem about nonce. But there was another error like 'Returned error: invalid sender' returned.

Answer (score 3):

The transaction object must be signed with private key transaction sender.
If it is showing **nonce too low** then it means that means the private key does not belongs to the sender of the transaction.

[Find working code here :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61456821/why-a-transaction-with-nonce-0-gets-failed-in-etherum)

Comment: Nice Tnx it's work