# Why a transaction with nonce 0 gets failed in etherum?

Tags: node.js, ethereum, metamask

I did transaction from a newly generated metamask account.
The txNonce value was 0 and this caused an exception that says **Error: nonce value is invalid**

Here is my code :

````
                    let txnObject = {
                        from: privateKeyToaddress.address,
                        to: process.env.HANDLER_CONTRACT,
                        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('20', 'Gwei')),
                        gas: web3.utils.toHex('3500000'),
                        value: 0x0,
                        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txNonce),
                        data: myContract.methods.sellTokens(amountOfToken).encodeABI()

                    };
                    const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
                    let tx = new Tx(txnObject, { chain: 'ropsten', hardfork: 'petersburg' });
                    const ac1_pvtkey = Buffer.from(privateKey.substring(2, 66), 'hex');
                    tx.sign(ac1_pvtkey);
                    var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

                    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
                        .on('receipt', function (transactionReceipt) {
                            console.log("Transaction reciept ", transactionReceipt);
                            resolve(transactionReceipt);

                        }).on('error', function (err) {
                            console.log("Error Called: " + err);
                            reject(err)

                        })```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction() always return "Returned error: nonce too low"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182595/web3-eth-sendsignedtransaction-always-return-returned-error-nonce-too-low)

Comment: @PeterHall Thanks for sharing, my code is working !!, I just want to know why it doesn't work with nonce value 0 ?

Comment: A nonce is a use-once value. You need to increase it for every transaction.

Comment: I apolozise ! Yes It increases evey time we make transaction... why it throws error when its my first transaction from the address ?

Comment: @PeterHall , i am sorry if i have misunderstood you but here is  a trnx with nonce 0 which  worked pretty fine: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xbab82c5e3f0ffe8ddcc5b538a35385059e7f7a20e8ee86bb32f6f06578e6e1b5